# How to handle Errors while using pipe and mergemap in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the below code calling two APIs. How can I handle errors in this, if there are any errors in first API call then the second API should not be called.

```
this.userService.signUp(this.signUpForm.value.fullName, this.signUpForm.value.email, this.signUpForm.value.password)
        .pipe(mergeMap((res: any)=> 
          this.notificationService.sendVerificationEmail(res.email)))
        .subscribe((notificationResponse: any)=>{
            console.log(notificationResponse.message)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) instead of `mergeMap`.

`switchMap` requires the previous observable to be completed then only proceed to the next observable.

```
this.userService.signUp(this.signUpForm.value.fullName, this.signUpForm.value.email, this.signUpForm.value.password)
  .pipe(switchMap((res: any) => 
    this.notificationService.sendVerificationEmail(res.email)))
  .subscribe({
    next: (notificationResponse: any) => {
      console.log(notificationResponse.message)
    },
    error: (err: any) => console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: Created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-skkpfz?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for success and error observables.